# Configuring angular material with rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to build my first api in Rails. And for that I want to use angular for front-end and ruby for back-end . I managed to get angular working but for some reason I can't get angular-material to work. I tried using  [this](https://github.com/alexkpek/rails-angular-material)  gem and followed the instructions written there.
The problem I am facing with it that frankly it doesn't work, nor do I get a meaningful error from the web console.
The project I am trying to make can be found  [here](https://github.com/Skillvendor/PhotoProject)  . I know it needs a lot of code refactoring and so on, I am just trying to configure things at the moment.
On the web page this is the only thing that get displayed :

```
Primary (md-noink)
Disabled
```

from this command:

```
<section layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="center center">
      <md-button>{{title1}}</md-button>
      <md-button md-no-ink class="md-primary">Primary (md-noink)</md-button>
      <md-button ng-disabled="true" class="md-primary">Disabled</md-button>
      <md-button class="md-warn">{{title4}}</md-button>
      <div class="label">Flat</div>
    </section>
```

which makes me believe it doesn't work...
also this is a navbar that has to be green but is not:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
 <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">Brand</a>
 </div>
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Active</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action</a></li>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Another action</a></li>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Something else here</a></li>
         <li class="divider"></li>
         <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</li>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Separated link</a></li>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">One more separated link</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
   <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
     <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-8" placeholder="Search">
   </form>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action</a></li>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Another action</a></li>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Something else here</a></li>
         <li class="divider"></li>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Separated link</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you make your backend with the rails-api, a view is not created, so you don't have to worry about which angular gem to pick from. You can create another directory (and repository) for the client (your angular frontend) and [generate the frontend](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) there. Now all you have to worry about is getting data, whether JSON or XML, traveling between the API and your client.

You can find a step by step tutorial [here](http://www.angularonrails.com/ruby-on-rails-angularjs-single-page-application/).

Hope it works out!